# Array index out of bound exception for palindrome java program

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, palindrome

Why am i getting the array bound of exception? im beginner in programming. Please help me understand. I have tried to convert the string to char array and reverse the characters and convert the end result back to string and compare with the original string

```
/* to check if the entered string is palinrome or not*/
class Palin
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String name="anna";
int l=name.length();
int d=l/2;
char tmp;
char tmp1;
char[] arr = name.toCharArray();

for(int j=0;j<d;j++)  /*to swap the characters*/
{
tmp=arr[j];
tmp1=arr[l];
arr[j]=tmp1;
arr[l]=tmp;
l=l-1;
}

String str=String.valueOf(arr); /* to convert the swapped char array back to string*/
if (str==name)
System.out.println("True");
else
System.out.println("False");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An array of `N` entries can be accessed with an index between `0` and `N-1`.**

Change this:

```
tmp1 = arr[l];
```

To this:

```
tmp1 = arr[l-j-1];
```

And get rid of this:

```
l = l-1;
```

---

**By the way, swapping can be done in 3 assignment operations instead of 4.**

So you might as well change this:

```
tmp = arr[j];
tmp1 = arr[l];
arr[j] = tmp1;
arr[l] = tmp;
l = l-1;
```

To this:

```
tmp = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[l-j-1];
arr[l-j-1] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the exception is because you initially set l = to name.length().  When you go to access the char array at l it is out of bounds because the array will hold 0 - name.length() - 1. You need to initialize l to l = name.length() - 1; Also don't use == to compare strings do str.equals(name).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String name="anna";
**int l=name.length();**
int d=l/2;
char tmp;
char tmp1;
char[] arr = name.toCharArray();

for(int j=0;j<d;j++)  /*to swap the characters*/
{
tmp=arr[j];
**tmp1=arr[l];**
arr[j]=tmp1;
arr[l]=tmp;
l=l-1;
}
```

Here is fully functional code for your program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "anna";
        int l = name.length();
        int d = l / 2;
        l = l - 1;
        char tmp;
        char tmp1;
        char[] arr = name.toCharArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) /* to swap the characters */
        {
            tmp = arr[j];
            tmp1 = arr[l];
            arr[j] = tmp1;
            arr[l] = tmp;
            l = l - 1;
        }

        String str = String.valueOf(arr); /*
                                         * to convert the swapped char array
                                         * back to string
                                         */
        if (str.equals(name))
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");

    }
```

Comment: **int l=name.length();** this will be storing the length of the string "anna" which will be 4. So, the part that does l=l-1 will have 3 and reduce one by one on each loop. This is my understanding. Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: It will only reduce after you have already tried to access arr[4] which does not exist.  arr[0-3] are valid indexes you don't do l = l - 1 until after you already access arr[4]. That is the problem but not the only problem with the code.  Make sure to change str == name to str.equals(name).

Answer (score 0):

brsp05 is right, your exception comes from the use of `name.length()` as the last index.

To avoid errors like this in the first place, you could avoid working with arrays here and use the `StringBuilder`class instead. It provides a method to reverse a string:

```
String name = "anna";
String str = new StringBuilder(name).reverse().toString();

if (str.equals(name))
  System.out.println("True");
else
  System.out.println("False");
```

The usage of this method avoids a lot of unnecessary and error-prone code.